# Spring-boot app displaying JMS messages on WebPage via WebSocket

Tags: websocket, jms, spring-boot, stomp, sockjs

I need a simple web-app in spring-boot that listens for messages on a JMS queue and when arriving it should appear on a webpage via WebSocket.

I have searched for examples and found several individual; either WebSocket or JMS which I have tested on their own but have not succeeded in wiring it together.

I have searched for an example but not found any and in my mind I think it should be pretty easy since it's a very basic requirement.

Do you know about any example with JMS and HTML display via WebSocket that you can share or can give some hints or help for me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) comes to the rescue.

You can write `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` to read messages from JMS queue and forward them to the `<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter>`. Where the last one just sends messages to the connected WebSocket session(s).

See these Spring Integration samples on the matter:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jms

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/web-sockets

**UPDATE**

To send the message to all subscribed WebSocket session you should do something like this:

```
<int:splitter input-channel="enricheMessage" output-channel="sendMessage" apply-sequence="false">
    <int-groovy:script>
        @serverWebSocketContainer.sessions.keySet().collect {
            org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
                    .copyHeaders(headers)
                    .setHeader('simpSessionId', it)
                    .build()
        }
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:splitter>
```

With this Groovy script I retrieve `session ids` from the `serverWebSocketContainer` (all those connected clients), iterate over them to build messages to send them over their websocket. And `split` finally, to send to the `<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter>` one by one.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to the way but unfortunately I get not get it working.
I have merged the two examples together and it works and I have also been able to route JMS message payload to the WebSocket beans (e.g. headerEnricherChannel) but it complains of wrong session id and it seems to use the payload as session id. 

I would like to broadcast the same to all clients.
Any idea?